# AWS - cannot find Lighsail instance in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, amazon-lightsail

I created a WordPress app using Lightsail. It says it was created in Frankfurt Zone. However, I cannot see this instance in EC2 console. I want to create a Load Balancer for that app and add certificates, but I can't cause I  don't see this instance on the list. Any ideas where can I find this Lightsail instance in EC2 console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lightsail not shown in EC2 console, it's the main difference between the Lightsail and EC2, If you want to have more control on your EC2, so you should run EC2 instance instead of cheaper version Lightsail.

For more info about the Lighsail read the FAQ on the AWS website:

https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/

Also, you can use Lightsail load balancer instead of standard ELB on AWS, for more info read the following doc:

https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/features/load-balancing/